# Facebook PHP SDK post activity

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a users **Activity feed** on Facebook using the PHP SDK, is this possible? Or only with Javascript?

Here is my basic code to post to a users wall:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
     array(
         'link' => 'www.example.com',
         'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
     ));
```

I want to post to a users activity, how is this done? I've experimented with the code below but to no success.

```
$facebook->api('/me/application:view', 'POST',
         array(
             'item' => 'www.example.com',
         ));
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#create

Comment: But it doen't say anything about PHP, only JS

Comment: So what, there’s no big difference … API endpoint and method are the same, and parameters are given as an associative array when using PHP Facebook::api … you should be able to figure this out, don’t you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using opengraph in my apps right now, but hope this helps:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#publish

Also check this answer (there is an example in PHP):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383901/173299

Hope it helps you.